# dict contains fields not in fieldnames

Tags: python, django, csv, serialization

this is my function to make a csv file of a queryset

```
  def esport_to_csv(self, tweets):
        with open('tweets.csv', 'w') as new_file:
            fieldnames = ["tweet_id", "text" , "user_screen_name", "user_name", "user_verified", "created_at", "user_time_zone", "user_location", "favorite_count", "retweet_count", "user_followers_count", "user_friends_count"]
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            for tweet in tweets:
                line = []
                line.append(tweet["tweet_id"])
                line.append(tweet["text"])
                line.append(tweet["user_screen_name"])
                line.append(tweet["user_name"])
                line.append(tweet["user_verified"])
                line.append(tweet["created_at"])
                line.append(tweet["user_time_zone"])
                line.append(tweet["user_location"])
                line.append(tweet["favorite_count"])
                line.append(tweet["retweet_count"])
                line.append(tweet["user_followers_count"])
                line.append(tweet["user_friends_count"])
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

this is my server response

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 967563194582515712, 'RT @KEEMSTAR: When you have your fathers car &amp; you tell everyone on the internet that your 15 year old ass bought it. t.co/bUhhrPw0…', 'TKBrotherTK', 'Team Kalvin', False, '2018-02-25T06:23:36+05:30', 'Melbourne', 'Australia', 0, 0, None, None
```

this is from where function called

```
@list_route(methods=["post"])
    def get_created_in_range(self, request):
        response = {}
        data = request.POST
        start = dateutil.parser.parse(data['start'])
        end = dateutil.parser.parse(data['end'])
        page_no = data['page_no']
        export_to_csv = data.get('export_to_csv', "false")
        tweets = Tweet.get_created_in_range(start, end, int(page_no))
        serializer = TweetSerializer(tweets, many= True)
        if export_to_csv == "true":
           self.esport_to_csv(serializer.data)
        print(type(serializer.data[0]))
        response["data"] = serializer.data
        return Response(response, status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

if u can see find the function call above here it is

**if export_to_csv == "true":
       self.esport_to_csv(serializer.data)**

i have seen a solution online but i dont know how to apply it over here

Comment: ... why are you using a `list` with a `DictWriter`?

Comment: Because tweet is a dictionary type

Comment: `DictWriter` accepts a dictionary type... Thats why its called 'DictWriter'

Comment: @avigil but if i do this **csv_writer.writerow(tweet)** removing the line(list) i  get the same error. i guess problem is with the field names matching the data                                  this is the error message    **ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'truncated', 'lang', 'user_id', 'user_utc_offset'**

Comment: if your dictionary has extra fields you should pass `extrasaction='ignore'` when creating your `DictWriter` to tell it not to complain about those.

Comment: that makes it, thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a `dict` to `DictWriter`, and tell it to ignore extra fields if they are present. Try this:

```
  def esport_to_csv(self, tweets):
    with open('tweets.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ["tweet_id", "text" , "user_screen_name", "user_name", "user_verified", "created_at", "user_time_zone", "user_location", "favorite_count", "retweet_count", "user_followers_count", "user_friends_count"]
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t', extrasaction='ignore')
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for tweet in tweets:
            csv_writer.writerow(tweet)
```

Comment: can u also tell me how to append to a existing csv file, this code overwrites the existing

Comment: open in append mode: `open('tweets.csv', 'a')`